# xml_data plugin used by jsTree not working in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jstree

I am trying to use the JsTree plugin to display the hierarchial tree. Right now the tree is rendered properly only on Firefox browser, doesnot work in IE 8 or 9 or any other browser we tested. I am using the XML  format of data internally and recently found the xml_data plugin is not recognized by IE9 ..

The other option is to use JSON to render the data, so wanted to know if it should work fine with JSON , if yes, is there a way I can convert the XML data directly to JSON format somehow?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dataType = text instead of xml in ajax call your problem will solved :)

My **Employees_xml_flat.xml** file contains is as follows: you can add more nodes if you want

```
<item id="19001" parent_id="0"   >  
            <content><name>Vaibhav</name></content>                
        </item>  
        <item id="19002" parent_id="19003"   >    
      <content><name>Pri_dev</name></content> 
      </item>
```

See following sample code: This jsTree will work fine on IE, Mozila and Google chrome. Not tested on other browser

Use jsTree

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Employees_xml_flat.xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(xmlData) {
                $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
                    "xml_data" : {
                        "data" : xmlData
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="treeViewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We've used jquery.xml2json and it worked great as long as the XML passed in is valid.

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/